# Why Does Exchange Symmetry Stabilize Quantum Systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, exchange-interaction

When trying to solve Schrödinger equation approximately, we usually represent wavefunction of the system as the Slater determinant of some set of spin orbitals to take into account that fermions (electrons) are indistinguishable particles.

If we derive expression for energy of a quantum system using this determinant, what we get is that exchange term (integral) contributes to stability of quantum system. Such stabilization can't be explained by classical physics. In other words, when we take into account that electrons are indistinguishable particles, we get additional stabilization (exchange "interaction"). Chemical bonds can't be described without this interaction.

This derivation is clear, however I am not sure I understand, from physical standpoint (interpretation), why does indistinguishability lead to stabilization?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with stabilization? There are some papers and books by E. H. Lieb concerning the stability of matter...

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I mean that quantum systems have lower total energy compared to the same system behaving classicaly. This lower energy is due to exchange interaction which has a big influence on energy of quantum system. This effect is important in describing stability of chemical bonds.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Exchange stabilization is reffered to as exchange operator when energy of quantum system (such as a molecule) is derived via wave function which is described by a Slater determinant, so that wavefunction satisfies antisymmetric requirement